# Elasticsearch + Oracle JDBC River

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

Maybe this is a simple question but im new at ElasticSearch.. Installed es 1.4, Oracle 10g is up and running, jdbc plugin loaded in ES without issue. Marvel also working.. Tried to create a river with this statement in Marvel/Sense:

---

```
PUT _river/mydata/_meta 
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "url": “jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:SID",
        "user": “oracleusr",
        "password": “ oraclepass",
        "index": “myindex",
        "type": “mytype",
        "sql": "select * from aTable"
      }
}
```

---

And i get this error all the time:

```
{
   "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from (offset=0, length=323): [80, 85, 84, 32, 95, 114, 105, 118, 101, 114, 47, 109, 52, 99, 47, 95, 109, 101, 116, 97, 32, 10, 123, 10, 32, 32, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 106, 100, 98, 99, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 106, 100, 98, 99, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 100, 114, 105, 118, 101, 114, 34, 58, 32, 34, 111, 114, 97, 99, 108, 101, 46, 106, 100, 98, 99, 46, 79, 114, 97, 99, 108, 101, 68, 114, 105, 118, 101, 114, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 117, 114, 108, 34, 58, 32, -30, -128, -100, 106, 100, 98, 99, 58, 111, 114, 97, 99, 108, 101, 58, 116, 104, 105, 110, 58, 64, 49, 48, 46, 49, 57, 52, 46, 49, 55, 46, 49, 55, 51, 58, 49, 53, 50, 49, 58, 109, 52, 99, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 34, 58, 32, -30, -128, -100, 109, 52, 99, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100, 34, 58, 32, -30, -128, -100, 32, 109, 52, 99, 49, 50, 48, 57, 48, 53, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 34, 58, 32, -30, -128, -100, 109, 52, 99, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 32, -30, -128, -100, 112, 97, 105, 115, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 115, 113, 108, 34, 58, 32, 34, 115, 101, 108, 101, 99, 116, 32, 42, 32, 102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 77, 52, 67, 80, 65, 73, 83, 34, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125, 10, 125, 10]]; ",
   "status": 400
}
```

on the CLI i get:

```
    org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:562)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:490)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:413)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:189)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:511)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchParseException: Failed to derive xcontent from (offset=0, length=323)
```

I first though was a connection problem but checking around it seems its a problem with the mapping in ES & Oracle. Does someone have done ES+Oracle River integration? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that worked out really straigth forward. Instead of putting the command on the what i did is have a json config file like this:

```
{
    "type" : "jdbc" ,
    "jdbc" :{
        "strategy" : "oneshot",
        "driver" : "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "url" : "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:DNS",
        "user" : "user",
        "password" : "password",
        "sql" : "select * from aTable",
        "poll" : "1h",
        "scale" : 0,
        "autocommit" : false,
        "fetchsize" : 100,
        "max_rows" : 0,
        "max_retries" : 3,
        "max_retries_wait" : "10s"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "aIndex",
        "type" : "aType",
        "bulk_size" : 100
    }
}
```

and then call it with curl like this:

```
'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_river/jdbcriver/_meta' -d @config.json
```

I don't know it's a parser issue or what but this way worked like a charm.

Thanks